# Qual objetivo dos métodos setTag e getTag na View?

Tags: java, android

No `TextView` declarado desta forma abaixo, é usado o `1` como definição o atributo `android:tag`. Vejam:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvJonSnow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="1"
    android:text="Jon Snow" />
```

Programaticamente é usado os métodos `setTag()` e `getTag()`, desta forma abaixo:

```
 TextView tvJonSnow = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.tvJonSnow);
 tvJonSnow.setTag(1);
```

Qual objetivo dos métodos `setTag()` e `getTag()` na `View`? Em qual momento devem ser usados?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qual objetivo dos métodos setTag() e getTag()?

O objectivo de `setTag()` é permitir guardar um qualquer objecto.

Esse objecto pode ser depois recuperado com `getTag()`.

> Em qual momento devem ser usados?

Quando pretender associar alguma informação à view. É uma forma "fácil" de armazenar, na view, dados relacionados a ela, em vez de colocá-los em uma estrutura separada.

Um exemplo é a implementação do [padrão ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder). Nele é utilizada a tag do layout do item da ListView para guardar um objecto com as referências às suas views.
Isso permitirá obtê-las, sem a necessidade de repetidamente usar `findViewById()`.

[setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)) e [getTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag(int)) têm um *overload* que recebe um *resource id* para identificar o objecto, permitindo guardar mais de um.

Para utilizá-lo deve criar um arquivo na pasta `res/values` onde declara os *id's*:

***ids.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="object1" />
    <item type="id" name="object2" />
    <item type="id" name="object3" />
</resources>
```

<sub>Nota: substitua `objectX` pelos nomes que quiser.</sub>

Os métodos são utilizados assim:

```
view.setTag(R.id.object1, object1);
view.setTag(R.id.object2, object2);
view.setTag(R.id.object3, object3);

....
....

object2 = (...)view.getTag(R.id.object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que o setTag() e getTag() tenham várias funções, porém nos meus projetos eu uso da seguinte forma:

**CustomAdapter.class**

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {

    MyObject tema;
    private List<MyObject> items;

    customViewHolder.item.setTag(i);
    customViewHolder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             int clickPosition = (int) v.getTag();
             tema = items.get(clickPosition);

             /*Aqui consigo pegar os items das respectivas posições, 
             sem perder a posição que está vindo no parâmetro, 
             chamando o tema.name por exemplo*/
         }
     }
```